# How to display related post in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a beginner for rails application, I have troubled some issue which is display related  post, I already show post separately according to id I have not any idea how to show related post.

Below my code for show post separately according to id:

```
def postDetails
 @details= Post.find(params[:post_id])
end
```

Now how can I rich this solution?

Comment: Do you think you could edit explain what you are trying to achieve a bit better? **related post** can mean a thousand different things.

Comment: I need if I view like the title  **programming** then show in sidebar title **programming in ruby, web developer, programming in python. etc** just related programming

Comment: so you wanna find all posts what have same worlds in title??? Think it will be difficult. Use for it `tags` and find by same tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, so I'll delete if required.

--

Your question is highly ambiguous, meaning that it's open to interpretation in many different ways. Whilst not a problem, when it comes to application functionality, you need to be as specific as possible.

Contrary to the new buzzwords of "full stack engineer", "devops" etc - the core of computing is to design functions & algorithms which "compute" data. Your case is exactly the scenario where a professional developer would outline a [spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_specification), and work towards implementing it.

---

To answer your question as broadly as you asked it, you have to define **how** you wish to "relate" your posts.

There are several options (all involve *data sampling*) --

> - define each post by "tags" or similar categorization
> - create an algorithm to [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) the title, pull out keywords & search for them
> - have users specifically define which posts are "related"

As you can see, there is one constant with the above - you need a "benchmark" to associate data. Be it keywords, tags, associated posts - you have to be able to identify the data you want.

Thus, you'll have to define the [pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) you wish to employ. I can talk through each option; it would be too much to write without knowing how you want to do it.